# How do I change innerHTML which contains hex unicode character for another similar character with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have a website menu that shows the down-pointing arrow next to an item that has a submenu. This arrow ( ▼ ) is contained in a span like this:
`<span class="h-open-icon>&#9660;</span>`
and I want to change it to this:
`<span class="h-open-icon>&#9650;</span>` (this character: ▲)

In Javascript, I am attempting to use the following code (part of a larger script) - which works fine for changing plain alpha-numeric text (e.g. `innerHTML === "text"` etc) - to change it to the up-pointing arrow when the submenu is open:

```
let hstr = button.querySelector('.h-open-icon');
    if (hstr.innerHTML === "\&\#9660\;") {
        hstr.innerHTML = "\&\#9650\;";
    } else {
        hstr.innerHTML = "\&\#9660\;";
    }
```

But this is not working. I assume it must be something to do with escaping characters, but all I can find is help on how to remove them, not keep them. It's just the numbers following the # that I need to change. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have backslashes behind & and # if you don't want to escape them?

Comment: Because, in my ignorance, I thought that characters like &, # and ; had to be escaped to show that they were part of the contained text and not part of the script code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sidestep the issue by just including the symbols in the JS:

```js
let hstr = document.getElementById("toggle");
hstr.onclick = function(){
    if (hstr.innerHTML == "▼") {
        hstr.innerHTML = "▲";
    } else {
        hstr.innerHTML = "▼";
    }
}
```

```html
<button id=toggle>▼</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea that special characters could be used directly; I thought they had to be written 'long hand'.